# jQuery & PHP: Running action in background

Tags: jquery

so I want to do something like when you press on LogOut, you get a waiting message like "please wait.." while its running ucp.php?mode=logout in the background, and after it has loaded that it should refresh the site.

How should this be done??

I am new to jquery, but so far i gave my link a ID, called #logout, made a `<div id="message"></div>` and then in jquery i did:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tryout').click(function () {
        logOut();
    });

function logOut()  { 
  var postFile = 'ucp.php?mode=logout';
  $.post(postFile, function(data){
        $("#message").fadeIn('slow');
  });
}
```

Now is this right? And the line with #message, where it fades in, i don't really think its right because where's should i write the "Please wait" and the refresh part?

Please help me

Comment: Does logging out really take that long? A simple form submission should be fine (and will take less time then making a request, waiting for a response, then reloading the page).

Comment: To expand on david's point - if your log out fails halfway through, leaving the user halfway logged out, but still on a live page, you might end up with some odd behaviour.  Go with a submit.

Comment: @David Dorward can you provide me an example of what you mean by form submission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function logOut()  { 
  var postFile = 'ucp.php?mode=logout';
  $("#message").fadeIn('slow');
  $.post(postFile, function(data){
        window.location.reload();
  });
}
```